# Zabbix LLD : how to create items from json?

Tags: zabbix

A part of my application looks like this example :

We focus on car brands and number of cars in a garage

```
Ford 12
Toyota 20
Honda 8
etc...
```

Not very real but let's imagine that numbers change every hour (discovery rule period).
I use a userparameter on my host.

```
UserParameter=discovery.garage.cars, /home/data/car_count.sh
```

This script rerurns the refreshed number of cars :

```
{ "data": [
 {
 "{#BRAND}": "Ford",
 "{#NB}": "10",
 },
 {
 "{#BRAND}": "Toyota",
 "{#NB}": "21",
 },
 etc ...
 ]
} 
​
```

I create the discovery rule :

```
name : car brand
type : zabbix agent
key : discovery.garage.cars
update interval : 1h
```

I don't get errors in GUI, but I would like to create the dynamic items (brand) and see their dynamic value (nb) for my host.
I read several times the documentation, but I find that it explains very badly how to do this, and I can't do it.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You need two script for for a LLD:

- a script gives you the LLD list, so `[{"{#BRAND}: "..."}]`, and you usually set a long interval, `1h` or more.
- a script gives you the item value, for each brand, so the item value can return `10` for `Ford`, and you usually set a short interval, `1m` or less.

The LLD is meant to create a lot of similar items, with the same configuration and different values.

You can also make it so you have a single script, making the LLD a Dependent Item of the item that gives you everything, like this:

**a principal item that returns all data in a single json**
[image: principal item]

**a dependent item as discovery rule**
[image: discovery rule]

**with some JSONpath to (gr)ease the {#MACRO} syntax**
[image: jsonpath macro]

**and finally some dependent prototype items**
[image: prototype item]

**with the appropriate JSONpath**
[image: jsonpath]

And after all of this... what's the overhead and performance cost of having a LLD every few minutes, instead of every hour or so? Am I uselessly stressing the system?

Comment: Thank you Iron but it's not clear enough for my case .... 1/ the script is created with userparameter 2/ the discovery rule too 3/ could you show me step by step in MY case which items I must create ? Sorry but I need very clear steps to proceed

Comment: thanks, "making the LLD a Dependent Item of the item that gives you everything" that helped me